# Explanation of Output For Simple Reverse String Algorithm in C

Tags: c, recursion

This is just a simple program that reverses a string (shown below).

I understand how to actual recursion part of this works, I'm just a little confused about the output I am getting when putting print statements in specific places.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *reverse_string(char *x, int start, int end) {
    
    char ch;
    
    if (start < end) {
        ch = *(x + start);
        *(x + start) = *(x + end);
        *(x + end) = ch;
        printf("Before: %s\n", x);
        reverse_string(x, ++start, --end);
        printf("After: %s\n", x);
    }
    return x;
    
}

int main() {
    
    char testString[] = "ABCDEF";
    char *newString[7];
    
    printf("Original: %s\n\n", testString);
    
    *newString = reverse_string(testString, 0, 5);
    
    printf("\nReversed: %s\n", *newString);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I traced this program with pen and paper, I predicted that the output was going to look like this:

```
Original: ABCDEF

Before: FBCDEA
Before: FECDBA
Before: FEDCBA
After: FEDCBA
After: FEDCBA
After: FEDCBA

Reversed: FEDCBA
```

However, the actual output I am getting is:

```
Original: ABCDEF

Before: FBCDEA
Before: FECDBA
Before: FEDCBA
After: FEDCBA
After: FEDCBA
After: FEDCBA

Reversed: FEDCBA
```

It might be a little hard to see but the first two "Before" print statements between what I predicted and what actually happened are different.

I'm just a little confused as to why are they all the same??

Any explanation for this would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: `char *newString[7];` isn array of 7 *character pointers*, not 7 characters. You probably mean `char *newString`.

Comment: There's no difference between your expected and actual output. Did you copy one of them wrong?

Comment: @Barmar Right - sorry, but still, using `int` for pointer arithmetic doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: You could use `size_t`, but it's not really important.

Comment: And after you fix the declaration that @tadman identified, you should use `newString = reverse_string(...);`. But `reverse_string()` reverses the string in place, it doesn't return a new string, so it's not clear why you need to return anything.

Comment: I think what you wanted is to move the `printf("Before: %s\n", x)` call to be the first statement inside the `if( start < end )` statement, **before** `ch = *(x + start);`.

Comment: Don't forget that for pointers you often mean `x[y]` instead of `*(x + y)` for almost every conceivable instance, *especially* when doing multiple de-references, like `x[y][z]`.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I agree with your first comment. Although my original program still works, it is better to practice using `char *newString` over what I had before.

Comment: You had an array for no reason. Normally you'd expect to see `char newString[LENGTH]` or `char* newString`, though in the case of the former you'd need to `strcpy()` to it, `=` won't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I didn't realize the outputs were the same.
Just checked my program and I did have them copied right.
I guess I was right about my prediction of the output after all LOL.
Sorry for the inconvenience everyone.